# How to perform query to get latest data?

Tags: mysql

**myTable**:

```
DATE      NAME   POCKET1   POCKET2   LOCATION  
1/1/2010  john   5         30        home  
2/1/2010  John   4         10        school  
3/1/2010  john   2         20        mall
```

I need help to query `myTable`, to get as in the expected result.
I know how to get the max & avg, but do not know how to get the latest `LOCATION`.

```
select NAME,max(POCKET1),avg(POCKET2) from myTable
where NAME = 'john' group by NAME;
```

**Expected result**:

```
NAME   max(POCKET1)   avg(POCKET2)   LatestLOCATION  
john   5              20             mall
```

Comment: thanks Nisse Engstrom. this is my first post, dont know how to make it readable like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

get Top 1 order by date desc

```
select 
  NAME
  ,max(POCKET1)
  ,avg(POCKET2) 
  , (select location from mytable order by date desc limit 1) as Location
from myTable 
where NAME = 'john' group by NAME;
```

if you want to get the latest location done by John

```
   select 
      NAME
      ,max(POCKET1)
      ,avg(POCKET2) 
      , (select location from mytable y where y.name = x.name order by date desc limit 1) as Location
    from myTable x
    where NAME = 'john' group by NAME;
```